# Thermodynamic and Transport properties input files for Chemkin

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

I am using Chemkin pro 2009 version. I want to model a decomposition+combustion reaction on my catalyst in a plug flow reactor.So I'll need to create my own Thermodynamic and Transport Properties file for my own material.

Can you anyone tell me what's the format for the various input files for Chemkin Pro? I have thermodynamic and some diffusion data for my system. Just need to know how to arrange that data in a text file.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't know the program, nor their handbook (e.g., [a senior version ?] https://www3.nd.edu/~powers/ame.60636/chemkin2000.pdf, p. 17). A limited search yields tutorials about this program on youtube (note, for example the section past 1:36 min:ss of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lq0mbHuABY stating «let's use the pencil icon to see the [chemkin] files' content»), and a page by MIT about modeling combustion including reaction mechanism, thermodynamic properties, and transport data in three chemkin files shared with the public http://web.mit.edu/anish/www/MITcomb.html, too as a reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot .I found thermo file format and mechanism file format ,still searching for transport properties file format

Comment: According to a pdf (https://personal.ems.psu.edu/~radovic/ChemKin_Tutorial_2-3-7.pdf, p. 2/274), «To request technical support ... support@ReactionDesign.com».  MIT's group around professor Howard no longer exists, yet their reaction engineering continues (https://cheme.mit.edu/research/catalysis-and-reaction-engineering/). I speculate the departmental chair (https://cheme.mit.edu/people/faculty/) may help to identify those continuing to use this program possibly licensed for the department rather than just by one group.  Good luck.